# stuck on implementation of merge sort

Tags: arrays, c, mergesort

I am implementing mergesort referencing the geeks for geeks implementation as a guide but my implementation is not working.

I have my mergesort function that divides my given array in 2 and calls mergesort on half of the list.

Within mergesort, I use a helper function that merges the sub arrays together.

I have included my 2 functions. Could someone be my second set of eyes, I am have staring at this too long to tell the difference between 1's and l's

It is running but not sorting correctly.

```
void merge(int arr[], int temp[], int l, int m, int r) {
  //TODO: implement merge.
  // check arr
  if (arr == NULL) {
        return;
  }

  int left = m - l + 1;
  int right = r - m;

  // copy array into temp array 
  // first half
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < left; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[l + i];
  }
  // second half
  int j = 0;
  for (j = m + 1; i < right; j++) {
        temp[j] = arr[m + l + i];
  }

  // compare from each end inserting the lower into the next location of the real array 
  // beginning index of front sub list
  int front = 0;
  // beginning of back sub list
  int back = left;

  // index within array to insert back in 
  int index = l;
  while ((front < left) && (back < right)) {
        
        if (temp[front] <= temp[back]) {
            // temp front goes in the next array spot
            arr[index] = temp[front];
            // increase temp
            front++;
        } else {
            // back is smaller and is put back in the list first 
            arr[index] = temp[back];
            // increase back 
            back++;
        }
        // increase array index
        index++;
  }

  while (front < left) {

        arr[index] = temp[front];
        front++;
        index++;
  }

  while (back < right) {

        arr[index] = temp[back];
        back++;
        index++;
  }
}

void mergeSort(int array[], int temp[], int l, int r) {

    if (r > l) {

        // find middle point
        int middle = l + (r - l) / 2;

        // call merge on first half
        mergeSort(array, temp, l, middle);

        // call merge on second half
        mergeSort(array, temp, middle + 1, r);

        // merge the halves
        merge(array, temp, l, middle, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: At a minimum, in your _last_ `while` loop, I think you want: `arr[back] = temp[back];` --> `arr[index] = temp[back];`

Comment: Have you run the program in a debugger and traced it as it runs? If so what did you find? Where does it start to first go wrong?

Comment: This loop `for(i = 0; i < r + 1; i++) {` is completely overwriting the results from the previous loop, and further if `m` is anything other than zero, it is copying far too much of the array (and indexing out of bounds).

Comment: @TomKarzes - thank you for pointing out that line, I realized I had not updated the most recent code. It has been edited to reflect my most recent commit

Comment: @lizard Ok, now the loop looks like `for(j = m + 1; i < right; j++) {`  Since `i` never changes in the loop, this loop will either not execute at all, or will be infinite.  In either case, it's very wrong.  If you have two independent loop indices, then they *both* have to change on each iteration.

Comment: @TomKarzes - yep that certainly did not get updated correctly thank you. The algorithm still isn't sorting though. Looking for a debugger. I am so stumped

Comment: @lizard Well, you need to sort out your loops.  I suspect they still aren't right.  If copying from array `a` to array `b`, check the index used for `a`, and check the index used for `b`, and make sure the loop will move them through their correct respective value ranges.  So far, in the code you've posted it hasn't.

Comment: At this point it sounds like that code you're working with is quite different from the posted code.  If so, then you should either update your code, or else just delete the question.

Comment: If you realize that you have been "staring at this too long to tell the difference between 1's and l's" it is probably time to use some better variable names

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem here:

```
  // second half
  int j = 0;
  for (j = m + 1; i < right; j++) {
        temp[j] = arr[m + l + i];
  }
```

You should write:

```
    // second half
    for (i = 0; i < right; i++) {
        temp[left + i] = arr[m + 1 + i];
    }
```

> Could someone be my second set of eyes, I am have staring at this too long to tell the difference between `1`'s and `l`'s?

This is an excellent point! The solution is to never use `l` as a variable name, and to simplify the `mergesort` implementation to remove the confusing and error prone `+1` / `-1` adjustments.  For this you just need to use the convention where `r` is the index of the element after the end of the slice.

Here is a modified version:

```
void merge(int arr[], int temp[], int lo, int mid, int hi) {
    // check arr
    if (arr == NULL) {
          return;
    }

    int left = mid - lo;
    int right = hi - mid;

    // copy array into temp array 
    // first half
    for (int i = 0; i < left; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[lo + i];
    }
    // second half
    for (int i = 0; i < right; i++) {
        temp[left + i] = arr[mid + i];
    }

    // compare from each end inserting the lower into the next location of the real array 
    // beginning index of front sub list
    int front = 0;
    // beginning of back sub list
    int back = left;

    // index within array to insert back in 
    int index = lo;
    while ((front < left) && (back < right)) {
        if (temp[front] <= temp[back]) {
            // temp front goes in the next array spot
            arr[index++] = temp[front++];
        } else {
            // back is smaller and is put back in the list first 
            arr[index++] = temp[back++];
        }
    }

    while (front < left) {
        arr[index++] = temp[front++];
    }

    while (back < right) {
        arr[index++] = temp[back++];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int array[], int temp[], int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi - lo >= 2) {
        // find middle point
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;

        // call merge on first half
        mergeSort(array, temp, lo, mid);

        // call merge on second half
        mergeSort(array, temp, mid, hi);

        // merge the halves
        merge(array, temp, lo, mid, hi);
    }
}
```

The initial call should give `0` and the length of the array as index arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble understanding your `merge` logic.

Too many indexes/limits of the form (e.g): `m - l + 1`

So, I simplified things by having *two* `temp` pointers: `tmp_l` and `tmp_r` and added some length/count variables.

This allowed some of the indexes to start with 0.

Also, your `middle` calculation was unusual.

And, I changed the arg in the call to `merge` from `middle` to `middle + 1`

---

I've refactored the code and added a test suite. I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif
```

Anyway, here's my [working] version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
    } while (0)
#endif

void
merge(int arr[], int temp[], int l, int m, int r)
{

    if (arr == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // get number of left elements
    int lcnt = (m - l);

    // get number of right elements
    int rcnt = (r - m) + 1;

    dbgprt("merge: BEGIN l=%d m=%d r=%d lcnt=%d rcnt=%d\n",
        l,m,r,lcnt,rcnt);

    int i = 0;

    int *tmp_l = &temp[0];
    for (i = 0; i < lcnt; i++)
        tmp_l[i] = arr[l + i];

    int *tmp_r = &temp[lcnt];
    for (i = 0; i < rcnt; i++)
        tmp_r[i] = arr[m + i];

    int front = 0;
    int back = 0;

    int index = l;

    while ((front < lcnt) && (back < rcnt)) {
        // temp front goes in the next array spot
        if (tmp_l[front] <= tmp_r[back]) {
            arr[index] = tmp_l[front];
            // increase temp
            front++;
        }

        // back is smaller and is put back in the list first
        else {
            arr[index] = tmp_r[back];
            // increase back
            back++;
        }

        // increase array index
        index++;
    }

    while (front < lcnt) {
        arr[index] = tmp_l[front];
        index++;
        front++;
    }

    while (back < rcnt) {
        arr[index] = tmp_r[back];
        index++;
        back++;
    }
}

void
mergeSort(int array[], int temp[], int l, int r)
{
    int middle;

    if (r > l) {
        // find middle point
#if 0
        middle = l + (r - 1) / 2;
#else
        middle = (l + r) / 2;
#endif

        dbgprt("msort: ENTER l=%d m=%d r=%d\n",l,middle,r);

        // call merge on first half
        mergeSort(array, temp, l, middle);

        // call merge on second half
        mergeSort(array, temp, middle + 1, r);

        // merge the halves
#if 0
        merge(array, temp, l, middle, r);
#else
        merge(array, temp, l, middle + 1, r);
#endif

        dbgprt("msort: EXIT l=%d m=%d r=%d\n",l,middle,r);
    }
}

void
dotest(int tstno)
{

    int count = (rand() % 30) + 1;
    printf("dotest: %d %d\n",tstno,count);

    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * count);
    int *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp) * count);

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx) {
        arr[idx] = count - idx;
        dbgprt(" %d",arr[idx]);
    }
    dbgprt("\n");

    mergeSort(arr,tmp,0,count - 1);

    int err = 0;
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx) {
        printf(" %d",arr[idx]);
        if (arr[idx] != (idx + 1)) {
            printf("?");
            err = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    if (err)
        exit(1);

    free(arr);
    free(tmp);
}

int
main(void)
{

    for (int tstno = 1;  tstno <= 4;  ++tstno)
        dotest(tstno);

    return 0;
}

void
merge_ORIG(int arr[], int temp[], int l, int m, int r)
{

    if (arr == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < m - l + 1; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[l + i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < r + 1; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[m + l + i];
    }

    int front = l;
    int back = m + 1;
    int index = l;

    while ((front < m - l + 1) && (back < r - m)) {
        if (temp[front] <= temp[back]) {

            // temp front goes in the next array spot
            arr[index] = temp[front];
            // increase temp
            front++;

        }
        else {
            // back is smaller and is put back in the list first
            arr[index] = temp[back];
            // increase back
            back++;
        }

        // increase array index
        index++;
    }

    while (front < m - l + 1) {
        arr[index] = temp[front];
        index++;
        front++;
    }

    while (back < r - m) {
        arr[index] = temp[back];
        index++;
        back++;
    }
}
```